# Issue with three images side by side

Tags: html, css, image

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/M6g85/2/

**Summary**

The website I am working on is for an artist. In the gallery page, There is to be rows of three images side by side. The heights all will be the same size, but the widths are set to auto.

The issue is that the left and right images need to be snapped to the left and right, while the middle floats in the center. All with equal margins between them.

I created another class called "artWrapper", this is to keep the title text inline with the images.

**What I have tried**

I tried to set the left and right "artWrappers" positions to "absolute", and use left:0, right:0, but then the middle one doesn't have anything to float next to.

I tried setting the margins manually to force them to align, but the gaps between the images messes up when the images are different widths.

**What I am trying to do**

Get the left and right images to keep to the far left and right of the container, and the middle image centered with equal distance either side of the image.

The title text must remain in line above the image, and the image heights all the same, widths will vary.

****The Code****

**HTML:**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper left">
                <h2>Image 1</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper center">
                <h2>Image 2</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper right">
                <h2>Image 3</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#wrapper {
    width:700px;
    border:1px solid;
}
.col33 {
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-height:521px;
}
.artWrapper {
    display:block;
}
.left {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
}
.center {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.right {
    position:relative;
    right:0;
}
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Fiddle looks fine to me?

Comment: So since the images has variable width, if it's larger than window size, it'll scroll horizontally, right? fiddle looks fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of building this layout using inline-blocks.

Your HTML is good as is.

Try the following **CSS**:

```css
#wrapper {
    width:700px;
    border:1px solid;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 0;
}
.col33 {
    max-height: 521px;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 1;
}
.artWrapper {
}
.artWrapper img {
    display: block;
}
/* You could replace .clearfix element with a pseudo-element */
.clearfix {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
}
```

On the parent container `#wrapper`, set `text-align: justify` and `line-height: 0`.

For the `.col33` elements, set `display: inline-block` and `line-height: 1` (or some suitable value based on your typographic design).

Apply `display: block` to the `.artWrapper img` to prevent some extra white space at the bottom of the images.

On your `.clearfix` element, set `display: inline-block`, `vertical-align: top`, `width: 100%` and `height: 0`.

In order for `text-align: justify` to work, you need at least two lines of inline elements, in this case, the images form one line and `.clearfix` forms the second.  By setting the width of `.clearfix` to 100%, it takes up the whole line so it guarantees that there will always be a second line should you have very narrow images.  The `vertical-align: top` and `height: 0` gets rid of any extra white space due to leading of the default inline box.

It is important to set `line-height: 0` on the wrapper and then reset it for the `.col33` child elements, otherwise you get some residual white space between the bottom border and the content.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QM9Ub/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Spent a lot of time on this! Thanks. I'll take a look at your suggestions shortly.

Comment: Rather frustratingly, this doesn't display right on the website. The actual width of the site is 1100px, and it needs to have floats, as the same col33 is used with another col66 to display a 2 thirds image.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or some other CSS framework?

Comment: I can see it works in the fiddle. Just I think I have some other CSS that is causing issues. I'll mark as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question suggest remade decision based on your example  [Codepen DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KdjvD)
of course it is not a perfect solution but I think in the way of what you want to implement

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper left">
                <h2>Image 1</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper center">
                <h2>Image 2</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/550x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper right">
                <h2>Image 3</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid;
  text-align:center;
}
.col33 {
    /*width:33.33%;*/
    /*float:left;*/
  display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-height:521px;
}
.artWrapper {
    display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.left {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
}
.center {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.right {
    position:relative;
    right:0;
}
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need left, right and center class to do that. Just add **text-align:center** in **.artWrapper**

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid;
}
.col33 {
    width:33.33%;
    float:left;
    margin:0 auto;
    max-height:521px;
}
.artWrapper {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper">
                <h2>Image 1</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper">
                <h2>Image 2</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/400x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col33">
        <div class="artWrapper">
                <h2>Image 3</h2>

            <img src="http://placehold.it/200x486" alt="Krays" class="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using table and table-cell property, you can achieve this. Update your CSS like below.

```
#wrapper {
width:700px;
border:1px solid;
display:table;
}
.col33 {
display:table-cell;
max-height:521px;
width:auto;
}
.artWrapper {
 display:block;
}

.clearfix {
clear:both;
}
.left
{
text-align:left;
 }
.right
{
text-align:right;
}
.center
{
text-align:center;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/M6g85/7/)

Comment: Hey, Thanks for that. Except the text needs to stay at the top left of each image. I'll give it a try soon.

Comment: As you said, you want to align first image left and last image right. Also middle one in center part. How you exactly align the word top left for each image. You can align top left for each div.

Comment: The images to be aligned as, far left,  center, far right. The text needs to stay above each image inline with the top left of the image.